# VSCode json schema fileMatch pattern

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

In VSCode, I'm trying to add a sjson schema to a project I have. My `.vscode/settings.json` file is this:

```
{
    "json.schemas": [
        {
            "fileMatch": [
                "/*.json"
            ],
            "url": "https://path/to/url.json"
        }
    ]
}
```

```

This works, but it's currently applying to all .json files in all folders in the project, which I don't want. I want it to **only apply to all .json files in the root directory**.  What do I have to put in the `fileMatch` property to enable this?

### Update

Have tried the following. These work, but apply to every .json file:

- `"/*.json"`
- `"*.json"`

These don't work at all (no .json file gets the schema):

- `"${workspaceFolder}/*.json"`
- `"${workspaceFolder}*.json"`
- `"${workspaceFolder}\\*.json"`
- The above 3 without the `{}`
- The above 4 with `workspaceRoot`

Comment: You could just change the name of your root directory JSON files to match specific pattern, like: `*.root.json`. This way the schema only applies to them, even though it's not always the solution but could be a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into something similar, but instead of wanting to add everything in the root, I wanted to add all JSON files that are in a subfolder of the workspace (root) folder.
The solution I used was to add all JSON and then exclude the ones I didn't want (including the settings file itself):

```
{
    "json.schemas": [
        {
            "fileMatch": [
                "*.json",
                "!/.vscode/settings.json",
                "!/Some.json",
                "!/SomeOther.json"
            ],
            "url": "/Schema.json"
        }
    ]
}
```

The ones that needed to be excluded were just a few, so I could just name them all.

A similar approach mightwork in the original problem, with something like this:

```
{
    "fileMatch": [
        "*.json",
        "!/Folder1/*.json",
        "!/Folder2/*.json"
    ],
}
```

In only problem here is that VS Code doesn't seem to allow wild cards for folder names. So using Glob like matching to exclude `/*/*.json` or `/**/*.json` doesn't help, unfortunately.

Comment: Is your `/Folder1` a absolut path or a relative path? I would like to change the "*.json" to "./my-schemas/*.json" -> and "my-schemas" folder would be inside my working-folder-structure not on a "global" folder. So I can include them to my version control system.